# AlertDialog with EditText

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, textedit

In the activity_main.xml I have a button that opens a AlertDialog with two textedit fields (dialog_login.xml); but when I click on the "login" button, I try to store the textedit content in a string and I receive the following output:
"attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference".
I've noticed that if I put an EditText in the activity_main.xml file with the same id of that in the alert dialog, I get no error, so the program look for an EditText in the activity_main.xml, not in the dialog_login.xml.
How can I do? Thanks

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    EditText mUsername;
    EditText mPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_login, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setView(v);

                mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
                mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

                mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        try
                        {   String username = mUsername.getText().toString();   }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  }
                    }
                });

                mBuilder.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rese.login_session_dialog.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

dialog_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logintext"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Login Phase" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You `EditText` is not inside your Activity Layout you can not perform `findViewById` directly

Do `findViewById` like this

```
mUsername = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
mPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Instead of this

```
 mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
 mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
```

**`FYI`**  You can use like this

```
mUsername = v.findViewById(R.id.username);
mPassword = v.findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Comment: @Lorenzo happy to help u

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Problem Here

```
  v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_login, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setView(v);

                mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
                mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
```

and specifically here

```
  mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
  mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
```

thats Means you want to find your text In Activity Layout

FindViewById  shoud be from layout where widgets is there

so this will be correct

```
  mUsername = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
  mPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed **dialog reference** before getting dialog views

your dialog reference is 'v'.

get your dialog views like this way

**mUserName = (EditText) dialogRefernce.findviewById(R.id.username);**

```
mUsername = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
mPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Your dialog reference saved into 'v'. Without using dialog(view) reference you cant get views.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you are not getting view from inflated layout.

**You just need to replace this**

```
mUsername = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
mPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.password);
```

**by this**

```
mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
```

`v` is the actual view that contains your **EditText**.

by default findViewById getting view from Activity's binded layout that from **activity_main** and it has not your dialog's EdiText, that's why it giving `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
The way you find ID is incorrect Please replace


b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_login, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setView(v);

                mUsername = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
                mPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.password);

                mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        try
                        {   String username = mUsername.getText().toString();   }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  }
                    }
                });

                mBuilder.show();
            }
        });
    }
```